# How to mutate an array using a function in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have a problem. The setup is more complex than what I show here, but that is to make the problem more understandable. Imagine I have the following script:

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  world_exports = np.zeros((4, 1))

  def sum_country_exports(nation, vector):
      vector = np.add(np.array(vector), np.array(exports[nation]))

  countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Mexico']

  list_X = [[10, 20, 40], [30, 40, 20], [40, 50, 60], [60, 70, 30]]
  exports = pd.DataFrame(list_X, columns = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Mexico']) 

  for country in countries:
      sum_country_exports(country, world_exports)
```

I have quarterly data on the exports of three countries (US, Canada, and Mexico). The idea is that the `world_exports` object is the sum of the exports of these countries for each quarter. It is crucial that this object is created outside the function.

Then, I want to loop over the exports of each of these countries and add it to the `world_exports` array. Therefore, the expected result would be 10+20+40=70 for the first quarter (etc. for the other three quarters).

Currently, `world_exports` goes back to zero each time the loop moves on to a new country.

I already tried changing `vector = np.add...` to `vector[:] = ...` within the function. It changed the results, but they were very strange and not correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `weighted_growth_goods` does not contain 81 zeros, it is an array with shape `81x0`, which means it has zero elements. Besides that, when you do `weighted_growth_goods_array = ...` in your function you are just changing the object referenced by the function-local variable `weighted_growth_goods_array`, if you want to change the contents of the same array object use slice assignment, e.g. `weighted_growth_goods_array[:] = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As for the 81x0, that was a type a made writing the post, sorry about that.
As for the slice, I added it and when I print weighted_growth_goods I indeed no longer get a bunch of zeroes. However, the results are still very strange. There are only integers and none of them are correct. Do you happen to know what caused this? I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm still new to this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, so I don't know what may be the issue. If you could update your question with a small reproducible example that we could try, including the result that you get and the result that you expected, it might be easier to tell what's going on.

Comment: I rewrote the question, hopefully it's more understandable now.

Comment: You should try to give us a [mcve] with a sample input data so that we can reproduce. Without knowing what exactly is `exports` I cannot guess what happens under the hood.

Comment: How do I add an .xslx file?

Comment: You merely describe your problem, but don't actually ask a concrete question. What are you trying to achieve? (In high level terms) Compute the total amount of exported goods per country?

Comment: The aim is to sum the exports of all countries for every quarter. Ideally, this is achieved by looping a function.

Comment: Can you provide an example that I can copy into my console and run without `NameError`?

Comment: I added some data, this you could run:
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        world_exports = np.zeros((4, 1))

        def sum_country_exports(nation, vector):
            vector = np.add(np.array(vector), np.array(exports[nation]))

        countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Mexico']

        list_X = [[10, 20, 40], [30, 40, 20], [40, 50, 60], [60, 70, 30]]
        exports = pd.DataFrame(list_X, columns = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Mexico']) 

         for country in countries:
             sum_country_exports(country, world_exports)

Comment: I don't know how to add the codeblocks in the comments so I added it to the original post.

Comment: @PeterDeVries: This is indeed the correct way: code should never be added in comments (except if **very** short) but edited into the question.

Comment: someone on reddit helped me solve it, for those interested: https://www.reddit.com/r/Numpy/comments/i2x44b/how_to_mutate_an_array_using_a_function/ 
Thanks to everyone that tried to help me solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in Python. Even if a type is mutable, `x = exp` never changes the referenced object but makes the local variable point to a new one.

That means that all your calls to `sum_country_exports` consistently pass the original `world_exports`, the local variable `export` in the sum is made to point to the new expression, and the value is just discarded when the function returns, leaving the original object untouched.

How to fix?

Unrelated, but the original shape of vector should be (4,) and not (4,1). In my tests I used `world_exports = np.zeros(4)`

1. mutate a passed parameter

   You could pass a list containing `world_export` and change the first (and only) element of that list. On the end, the list will contain the expected value:

   ```
    def sum_country_exports(nation, vector):
        vector[0] = np.add(np.array(vector[0]), np.array(exports[nation]))

    lst = [world_exports]
    for country in countries:
        sum_country_exports(country, lst)

    print(lst[0])
   ```

   With the sample data, it gives:

   ```
    [ 70.  90. 150. 160.]
   ```
2. *return* the new value

   As you change only one value, it is IMHO much simpler (and less error prone) to just return that value:

   ```
    def sum_country_exports(nation, vector):
        return np.add(np.array(vector), np.array(exports[nation]))

    for country in countries:
        world_exports = sum_country_exports(country, world_exports)

    print(world_exports)
   ```

   It gives too:

   ```
    [ 70.  90. 150. 160.]
   ```

   I prefere this second way, because with my first code, `lst[0]` does contain the expected values, but `world_exports` is still 0.
3. use the `out` parameter of `np.add`

   `np.add` allows to store the result in a ndarray having the expected shape. This allows to actually mutate the passed array:

   ```
    def sum_country_exports(nation, vector):
        np.add(np.array(vector), np.array(exports[nation]), out=vector)

    for country in countries:
        sum_country_exports(country, world_exports)

    print(world_exports)
   ```

   It gives too:

   ```
    [ 70.  90. 150. 160.]
   ```

   This is probably what you want, but is numpy specific.